# Check if user is authenticated Android WebView

Tags: android, authentication, webview, xamarin

I have an Url which I load in a WebView. This url loads up an authentication page eg. Gmail. I want to check if the user is completely authenticated.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

This is what I have done :-

Activity

```
mWebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            mWebView.SetWebViewClient(new AuthWebViewClient(Name, Id,HUrl,endHost)); 

            mWebView.LoadUrl(AuthUrl);
```

AuthWebViewClient

Comment: Use method OnActivityResult() for get result data back to activity.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani Can you explain a little more?

Comment: what code you have done? and what you want to authenticate? gmail or your own page authentication?

Comment: @sud I have added my code. I want to authenticate my own page

Comment: But why you try google authentication in your `WebView`? Google gives that own authentication dialog using account manager dialog.

Comment: then you can set a final url in webpage for success. suppose when user successfully authenticate then forward the url to page success.php... then check is that url loaded in webview if yes then do what you want

Answer (score 0):

look at this code what i have used... here `String url` is your current url on webpage

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            String curr_url = url.toString();
            if(curr_url.equals("http://mywebsite.in/success.aspx?id=1"))
            {
                try {
                    // here your come when user successfully authenticate then do what you want
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: here url `http://mywebsite.in/success.aspx?id=1` is loaded on web page only when user successfuly authenticated

Comment: this useful for your own websites custom authentication for google you should follow google authentication

Comment: Is there any other way? I ahve tried this initially but it didnt work

Comment: I was doing the above in OnPageFinished(). But when I transferred the code to shouldOverrideUrlLoading(), the method is never called.

Comment: try this on loadresources, but it should be better if you try this in shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Comment: The problem is if I do this Native Android it works. But It does not work for Xamarin

Comment: sorry i dont have much knowledge about xamarin